# Need help in finding cause of an error in quicksort implementation in C

Tags: c

I am getting some strange error in Xcode - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the below piece of code

```
while(*w1 != '\0' && *w2 != '\0')
```

Here is quicksort implementation and compare method:

```
void quicksort(char ***words, int start, int end){ //start is pivot
    if(start >= end){
        return;
    }
    int left = start;
    int right = end;

    int comp;
    while( left <= right ){
        do{
            char* w1 = (*words)[++left];
            char* w2 = (*words)[start];
            comp = compare(w1, w2);
        }while(comp < start); //while current left less than pivot

        do{
            char* w1= (*words)[--right];
            char* w2= (*words)[start];
            comp = compare(w1, w2);
        }while(comp >= start); //while current right is more or equal to pivot

        if(left < right){
            swap(words, left, right);
        }
    }
    swap(words, start, --left);
    quicksort(words, 0, left-1);
    quicksort(words, left+1, end);
}

int compare(char *w1, char *w2){
    while(*w1 != '\0' && *w2 != '\0'){
        if( *w1 < *w2 ){
            return -1;
        }else if( *w1 > *w2 ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            w1++;
            w2++;
        }
    }

    if(*w1 == *w2)
        return 0;
    else if(*w1 == '\0')
        return -1;
    else return 1;
}
```

Here is full code http://ideone.com/MZFaFO

I assume the cause of the problem can be between do-while. I am doing pretty bad with pointers.. I will be very thankful for your help. I just started to learn C and it totally kills me. :(

Comment: Can you explain why you're taking in as input a `char***`? I can understand two stars (for an array of strings), but the third star I'm not so sure about.

Comment: I don't understand why you're making `swap` needlessly complex. If swapping two elements of an "array", passing a pointer to that "array" is pointless.

Comment: Is `end` the last element? (Usually, it's the length of the array--and thus `end` points beyond the last word). OT: in the first line of `compare` you only have to check *one* word for its terminating zero.

Comment: @chris erm... 1. I am not sure how to do it other way...I just started to learn C.
2. I still need to practice pointers.. they make lots of pain for me.

Comment: @Jongware yes, end is the last index. Why I should check only one word? How would I know which one is shorter?

Comment: If *either* of the pointers point to a zero, the next two `if` tests will return the correct result. Only when they are equal, they might both be zero *or* (for other characters) the same, and so you can put your string end test there. It's unrelated to your error; you might want to print the values of `left` and `right` to test where they go out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of things wrong (more on that in a moment), but I have to open with this:

*Don't pass right/left index markers for a quicksort implementation*. You don't need them, and the amount of complexity they introduce to the general algorithm is not worth it. This is C. With that you get pointer arithmetic *for free*. Use it; *revel in it*. With that your algorithm reduces to *one* place where offset-magic is done. The rest becomes trivial.

But first, some general housekeeping, starting with your comparator. You be the judge if this is simpler or not:

```
int compare(char const *w1, char const *w2)
{
    while(*w1 && *w2)
    {
        if (*w1 < *w2)
            return -1;

        if (*w2++ < *w1++)
            return 1;
    }
    return *w2 ? -1 : (*w1 != 0);
}
```

The only thing worth talking about in this is the last clause, which says: "If we finished with `w2` still pointing to something, it must be longer than `w1`, so `w1` is "less" and we return -1. Otherwise, `w2` must be at string-end, so return 1 if `w1` is not (and is therefore "greater"), otherwise return 0 (they're both at string-end).

Regarding `swap`-ing elements. You're doing little more than swapping *pointer* values (address) that reside in your pointer array. Therefore...

```
void swap_ptrs(char **lhs, char **rhs)
{
    char *tmp = *lhs;
    *lhs = *rhs;
    *rhs = tmp;
}
```

On to the meat of your problem(s) (there are multiple). First, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with *this*:

```
    do{
        char* w1 = (*words)[++left];
        char* w2 = (*words)[start];
        comp = compare(w1, w2);
    }while(comp < start)
```

`start` is an index to your array of pointers, `comp` is the result of a comparison. It doesn't return an index, it returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`. They literally have *nothing* to do with each other. The identical problem happens in your second while-loop. Furthermore, you're incrementing `left` (and decrement `right` in the other loop) *prematurely*. In short, there is simply no way this can `quicksort` *at all*.

Utilizing the pointer math mentioned earlier as well as the comparator and swap routine provided, this is one way to quicksort the partitions in question. Note we only need two parameters: the base address of an array, and the length of the sequence we desire to sort. The recursion using pointer arithmetic to provide the proper starting point and length when needed.

```
void quicksort(char **words, size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    char const *pvt = words[len/2];
    size_t lhs = 0, rhs=len-1;

    while( lhs < rhs )
    {
        while (compare(words[lhs], pvt) < 0)
            ++lhs;

        while (compare(words[rhs], pvt) > 0)
            --rhs;

        if (lhs <= rhs)
            swap_ptrs(words+lhs++, words+rhs--);
    }

    quicksort(words, rhs+1);
    quicksort(words+lhs, len-lhs);
}
```

To test this, a simple random-string-generationg implementation:

```
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    // allocate a string bed of 100 pointers
    static const size_t len = 100;
    char **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * len);

    // populate with random strings ranging from 5 to 8 chars.
    for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        int siz = 5 + rand() % 4;
        arr[i] = malloc(siz+1);
        for (size_t j=0; j<siz; ++j)
            arr[i][j] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        arr[i][siz] = 0;
    }
    quicksort(arr, len);

    for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
ARSXTGA
ATQYX
BCFNHSN
BEDYEW
BGTYDCK
BSYNEB
BYQXH
BYXVID
CHXQVEVG
CLRLYLO
DEXTPQO
DXHAIP
ECLMAD
EPYCQJ
EPZGNCG
EUUWTXOI
FEABB
FFMCTK
FYOIIKX
FZQWIQ
GDDUOMO
GFJNWEKP
GGMHDPA
GQMSEU
HTPCU
HULIENC
IGNHGIMM
ITFPMUAM
IYHBOWJ
IYTDAOEE
JEQVXRZ
JMUCWRV
JUDMWMS
KHVKN
KJOJXNL
KQIVURG
KVIGK
KVUYIER
LACVY
LCEKGER
LGELOIY
MILDEFJI
MNZDX
MOBOAPYL
MOLDKACO
MUJXDGH
NDZZLRQD
NEZTSBPC
NLDHM
OAZSW
OLPKKL
OZOBK
PBIOISM
PCYHNYQ
PEZMH
PFWEJQI
PIXNQ
PZATCAIK
QJUYGNID
QKGDXI
QLGORE
QULGW
RBEDK
ROYSAPGH
RQTVMO
RTBGDBXM
SLHUOE
SLTBOETM
SNRIGY
SRBPOF
STGPU
STUOQ
SXZFPRR
TBRFT
TELZYQ
TJKWLLE
TKLSNN
TNATOPFQ
UJXGWM
UNQZSF
VCLZUWSV
VPJVAEP
WBVBY
WDVWTEF
WEPRL
WFTJSFIQ
WUIJQS
WWPOAQQ
XLASZMI
XOQTSPZ
XQZZSZ
YFHXA
YFXMKAC
YPPUC
YRLVS
YTGHWVU
YWXOWXL
ZLVTUL
ZUNMCE
ZUUQZXLX
```

Comment: I have a question. I your main you declare pointer to pointer array. In quicksort method you also pass pointer to pointer. Why? Should not it be pointer to pointer to pointer?
Can you please explain -  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
and  char **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * len); <--- how can you take sizeof(*arr) if we did not specify size for *arr.....

Comment: @PutinHuylo The latter seeds the runtime library PRNG for later use when I generate the strings. Regarding the former, no, it does not need to be a pointer^3. I'm modifying what the pointer *points to* (a sequence of `char *`), not the pointer itself. It does not need to be passed by address. I'm only interested in its value (which is the base address of the pointer array).